# Do 4th Generation Macbooks need to have matching brands of RAM?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, memory, macbook, upgrade

I've been trying to replace the RAM in my 4.1 Macbook (circa 2007-2008).
It's one of the black plastic ones running Snow Leopard.
Original specs: 2GB RAM 250GB HardDrive
It's always been a great laptop.

The stock RAM that has been running fine for years is 2 x 1 GB DDR2 667 Mhz Hynix Brand RAM.

For my first attempt to upgrade RAM I bought 2 x 2GB DDR2 800 Mhz Ram (Kingston Brand) from Best Buy. The computer wouldn't start with it so I returned it. It seems this computer only likes 667 DDR2 RAM not 800 Mhz DDR2. My understanding was this is not supposed to be an issue.

I put the original RAM back in  and everything went back to normal...no issues except the need for **MORE** RAM. =(

Yesterday a friend gave me 2GB DDR2 667 Mhz Ram (Crucial Brand) that he had extra...brand new in the box. I plugged that in along with my old 1GB DDR2 667 Mhz Hynix RAM and the computer booted. System Profiler recognized it and I had 3 GB of RAM...cool! =)

Things went well for about 10 min and then the computer crashed. Just powered down in an instant. I tried to turn it back on and got 3 beeps and a black screen. I understand this means you have RAM issues. I pulled the battery and it started again.

Twice since it has frozen and nothing would work. I've since taken the RAM out and cleaned it and the RAM bays with pressurize air. It worked for 5 minutes then the computer shut off again.

I spoke to the local Mac store (we don't have an Apple store) and they wanted $190 for 4GB (2 x 2GB DDR2 @ 667 Mhz) of RAM giving me a story about how Apple uses special RAM which I seriously doubt. I think they just have high profit margins from fleecing suckers.

Do I need to have matching RAM amounts (like 2x2GB or 2x1GB) or matching brands of RAM?

What's my next step?

Should I order another stick of 2GB RAM from Crucial? They only want $40 bucks for 2GB of DDR2 667 Mhz. Sadly they're in the states and shipping to Canada takes way too long for my instant gratification based brain. Is there a good Canadian based source for macbook RAM?

Comment: Could you please cut down the unnecessary information? It makes your post harder to read.

Comment: @Daniel Beck anyone who doesn't want to read the story can just read the title, anyway. No big deal.

Comment: I don't know what's going on so I'm describing the situation. I know reading is hard and all. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order DDR2 667Mhz from Amazon. Name brand doesnt matter, but I would suggest Kingston. And no it doesnt matter if you have a 1 GB chip and a 2 GB chip, but its recommended that both chips are the same brand name if you have a choice. Your pc would shut down however, if you mix name brands, but I recommend staying with one company.